# Import folders from google colab to huggingface

Tags: import, google-colaboratory, huggingface

So, how do i save 2 folders from a google colab runtime to huggingface (i have a hf token bdw)?
The folders are
/content/stable/models/Lora
/content/stable/models/LyCORIS

and i want to save the Lora folder in: https://huggingface.co/PrivateCassy/Lora/tree/main
and the LyCORIS to save in: https://huggingface.co/PrivateCassy/LyCORIS/tree/main

This is what i tried but didn't work

````
import shutil
from transformers import datasets

# Hugging Face API token
api_token = input("the api tokken")

datasets.config.HfFolder.set_base_dataset_hf_folder('/content/hf_datasets')
datasets.set_hf_api_token(api_token)

Lora_LyCORIS_on_hf = "Load" #@param ["Save","Load"]

src = '/content/stable/'

match os.path.exists(src):
    case False:
      os.makedirs(src)
    case _:
      pass

match Lora_LyCORIS_on_hf:
  case "Save":
    # Upload Lora and LyCORIS to Hugging Face
    datasets.upload_dataset(src)
  case "Load":
    # Download Lora and LyCORIS from Hugging Face
    dataset_lora = datasets.load_dataset(src)

    # Copy downloaded data to the desired location
    shutil.copytree(dataset_lora.data_dir, src, dirs_exist_ok=True)```
````

Answer (score 0):

i actually found out how on my own and it was quite simple...

here is the code:

```
from huggingface_hub import login, HfApi

# Login 
login(token="tokken goes here")

api = HfApi()

# Upload folders
api.upload_folder(folder_path="/content/stable/models/Lora",  
                 repo_id="Username goes here/Lora",
                 repo_type="model")

api.upload_folder(folder_path="/content/stable/models/LyCORIS", 
                 repo_id="Username goes here/LyCORIS",
                 repo_type="model")
```

WARNING IT MAY DUPLICATE FILES AND THERE IS A ONE HOUR COOLDOWN BETWEEN USES